Expo Image component not displaying image
I am trying to display an image using the Image component from expo-image. I have tried using the Image component using react-native and using that one the image gets displayed but I would like to be able to use the one provided by Expo.
I can not seem to find what I am missing. This is what I have:
import { Image } from "expo-image";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
    Dimensions,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    useWindowDimensions,
    View,
} from "react-native";

export function Page() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Image
                style={styles.image}
                contentFit="contain"
                transition={1000}
                source={`../../assets/mockImages/image1.png`}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        flex: 1,
    },
});




I had the same issue, after hours of debugging I realized that if the Image was not wrapped with a View that has style flex:1, <View style={{flex:1}}> the image won't appear.
so this might be the issue that you are facing.
so based on your code it should be:
<View style={{flex:1}}>
            <Image
                style={styles.image}
                contentFit="contain"
                transition={1000}
                source={`../../assets/mockImages/image1.png`}
            />
</View>

even on their docs they wrap the Image with a View styled with flex:1 https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/image/#usage

Yes, that was my issue exactly!
This is what I've found too after hours of searching lol.
Thanks for the response!

Try using source={require('...')} when working with a local image to properly include it in the bundle:
        <Image
            source={require('../../assets/mockImages/image1.png')}
            // other props
        />

